# Accessing random forest results in Matlab

Tags: matlab, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I am estimating a random forest in Matlab and try to get information about the tree structure after estimation. In particular, for each tree in the ensemble, I want to figure out
- which path through the tree provides the highest/lowest and most/least accurate prediction.
- by which features and thresholds these paths are characterized by.

I find it difficult to access the Matlab results to do this. As a minimal example, consider the example from the help file:

```
load carsmall
b = TreeBagger(50,[Weight, Cylinders],MPG,'oobvarimp','on', 'method', 'r');
```

Now, e.g.

```
FirstTree = b.Trees{1,1};
```

provides the estimates for the first tree. The functions

```
FirstTreeNodeMeans = nodemean(FirstTree);
FirstTreeTerminalNodes = ~isbranch(FirstTree);
```

provide information about the average prediction in each node and which nodes are terminal ones. I can find the highest (and likewise lowest) prediction of all terminal nodes by e.g.

```
Highest = max(FirstTreeNodeMeans(FirstTreeTerminalNodes)) == FirstTreeNodeMeans;
```

My remaining question is this: Say, I found that node 4 is the one that I want. How can I extract the path that leads to node 4 (including split variables and cutoff-values)?

I would be thankful for any help, best,
Tom

Comment: Small note; your minimal working example does not run. Variables in the last line end with an 's'. Also, i don't understand why but `nodemean()` in your example seems to return an empty.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the typos. `nodemean()` returned an empty matrix because I loaded a classification rather than a regression problem as an example.